# How do I only sum the values in a column if they are equal in a corresponding column in excel?

Tags: excel

So I have a column in excel lets say

A1:A27 where there are just a bunch of random letters like a, b, c, etc

I also have another column full of numbers

B1:B27 where each is either 1, 2, 3, etc...

If there are 2 cells in A:A that contain z,

how do i sum up their corresponding values in B?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the sumif function, it should do what you need

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010342932.aspx

sumif(b1:b127,cell that contains letter you are searching for here,a1:a127)